# make axis of radar chart conditional to existence of value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a radar chart using the radar-chart.js library (built on top of D3).
I want to use the same code to show a radar chart for many countries. However, not all countries have all values.

[Here is a plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bv8Iqb9cqiFwKuEwPc4V?p=preview)

You'll see for the first example (Canada), nothing shows up. This is because it's missing a value for the produce axis. If you click on the dropdown to see the other countries, you'll see the radar charts show up for them, because they have all values.

How can I make the axes conditional based on whether they have values? At first I thought I could do this--

```
filteredCorn.forEach(function(d){
    if(d.value != NaN){
        return corn = d.value;
    }
    else {return 0}
});
```

but I don't want the values to be 0 if they don't exist, I want to remove the axis altogether. Any thoughts?

PS - I know I'll need to add svg.exit to clean this up then-- but that's not what I'm focusing on now. Thanks!

Full code:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .radar-container{
            position: relative;
            width: 500px;
        }
        .radarhead{
            position:relative;
            width:50%;
            float:left;
        }
        .radar-chart .area {
          fill-opacity: 0.7;
        }
        .radar-chart.focus .area {
          fill-opacity: 0.3;
        }
        .radar-chart.focus text {
            font-size:13px;
          text-shadow: 0px;
        }
        .radar-chart.focus .area.focused {
          fill-opacity: 0.9;
        }
        .area.average, .average .circle {
          fill: #ADD8E6 !important;
          stroke: none;
        }
        .area.currentCountry, .currentCountry .circle {
          fill: #00a0d5 !important;
          stroke: none;
        }
        svg#colors{
            float:right;
        }
        ul#radarleg{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            float:right;
        }
        li{
            list-style-type: none;
        list-style-image: none;
        padding-right: 7px;
        text-align: right;
        line-height: 142%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="opts">
            <option value="BRA">Brazil</option>
          <option value="CAN" selected="selected">Canada</option>
            <option value="ETH">Ethiopia</option>
            <option value="SUR">Suriname</option>
        </select>
    <div class="radar-container">
        <svg id="colors" width="20" height="40"><rect x="0" y="0" width="12" height="12" fill="#4dbce1"></rect><rect x="0" y="23" width="12" height="12" fill="#c5e4ed"></rect></svg>
        <ul id="radarleg">
        <li class="radarlegendcname"></li>
        <li>Average</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="radar-chart.js"></script>
    <script>
    var currentCountry;
    radartitle = "Exports";
    var filtered;

    function filterJSON(json, key, value) {
      var result = [];
      for (var country in json) {
        if (json[country][key] === value) {
          result.push(json[country]);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }

    d3.json("values.json", function(error, json){

        d3.select('#opts')
                .on("change", function () {     
                    var section = document.getElementById("opts");
                  currentCountry = section.options[section.selectedIndex].value;                
                    filtered = filterJSON(json, 'iso3', currentCountry);
                    updateChart(filtered);
                });

        console.log("json: ", json);
        currentCountry = "CAN"
        filtered = filterJSON(json, 'iso3', currentCountry);
        updateChart(filtered);

        console.log("filtered: ", filtered);
    });
    function updateChart(filtered){ 
        filteredCorn = filterJSON(filtered, 'id', 103706);
        filteredWheat = filterJSON(filtered, 'id', 103606);
        filteredSoy = filterJSON(filtered, 'id', 68606);
        filteredProduce = filterJSON(filtered, 'id', 38406);

        var corn, wheat, soy, produce;

        filteredCorn.forEach(function(d){
            if(d.value != NaN){
                return corn = d.value;
            }
            else {return 0}
        });
        filteredWheat.forEach(function(d){
            wheat = d.value;
        });
        filteredSoy.forEach(function(d){
            soy = d.value;
        });
        filteredProduce.forEach(function(d){
            produce = d.value;
        });

        console.log("corn", corn);
        console.log("wheat", wheat);
        console.log("soy", soy);
        console.log("produce", produce);

    var data = [
        {
        className: 'currentCountry',
        axes: [
          {indicator: "Corn", value: corn},
          {indicator: "Wheat", value: wheat},
          {indicator: "Soy", value: soy},
          {indicator: "Produce", value: produce}
        ]
      }
    ];
    RadarChart.defaultConfig.color = function() {};
    RadarChart.defaultConfig.radius = 1;
    RadarChart.defaultConfig.w = 400;
    RadarChart.defaultConfig.h = 300;

    var chart = RadarChart.chart();
    var cfg = chart.config(); // retrieve default config
    var radarhead = d3.select('.radar-container').append('text').attr('class','radarhead').html("<h3>" + radartitle + "</h3>");
    d3.select('.radarlegendcname').append('text').html(currentCountry);
    var svg = d3.select('.radar-container').append('svg')
      .attr('width', RadarChart.defaultConfig.w + 50)
      .attr('height', RadarChart.defaultConfig.h);
    svg.append('g').classed('single', 1).datum(data).call(chart);

    };
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and values.json is:

```
[
    {
      "id":103706,
      "iso3":"BRA",
      "country":"Brazil",
      "value":19
    },
    {
      "id":103706,
      "iso3":"CAN",
      "country":"Canada",
      "value":17.3
    },
    {
      "id":103706,
      "iso3":"SUR",
      "country":"Suriname",
      "value":10.3
    },
    {
      "id":103706,
      "iso3":"ETH",
      "country":"Ethiopia",
      "value":5
    },
    {
      "id":103606,
      "iso3":"BRA",
      "country":"Brazil",
      "value":8
    },
    {
      "id":103606,
      "iso3":"CAN",
      "country":"Canada",
      "value":8.17
    },
    {
      "id":103606,
      "iso3":"SUR",
      "country":"Suriname",
      "value":14.13
    },
    {
      "id":103606,
      "iso3":"ETH",
      "country":"Ethiopia",
      "value":14.5
    },
    {
      "id":68606,
      "iso3":"BRA",
      "country":"Brazil",
      "value":4.39
    },
    {
      "id":68606,
      "iso3":"SUR",
      "country":"Suriname",
      "value":5.25
    },
    {
      "id":68606,
      "iso3":"ETH",
      "country":"Ethiopia",
      "value":34.17
    },
    {
      "id":38406,
      "iso3":"ETH",
      "country":"Ethiopia",
      "value":21.4
    },
    {
      "id":38406,
      "iso3":"BRA",
      "country":"Brazil",
      "value":20
    },
    {
      "id":38406,
      "iso3":"SUR",
      "country":"Suriname",
      "value":7
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you add the axis on the basis of a condition.

Like if the value present add the axis:

Something like this:

```
var data = [
    {
    className: 'currentCountry',
    axes: [

    ]
  }
];
if (corn){
  data[0].axes.push({indicator: "Corn", value: corn})
}
if (wheat){
  data[0].axes.push({indicator: "Wheat", value: wheat})
}
if (soy){
  data[0].axes.push({indicator: "Soy", value: soy})
}
if (produce){
  data[0].axes.push({indicator: "Produce", value: produce})
}
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qpu3Vn213lze8uEgWtlo?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much, this is perfect. It really helps me out.